# Oil Pressure Sensor Leak

Tags: nissan, oil-leak, oil-pan, almera

I have a 99 Nissan Almera w/ GA16DE engine and there is a small oil leak from the oil pressure sensor and also from the oil pan gasket it seems.  They both seem to be just a few drops here and there, no puddles under the car or anything, although I did see fresh oil drops hanging from the sensor and oil pan area a few days after having the under side of the engine pressure washed.

Anything I need to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ Paulster2 has stated you need to determine where the sensor is leaking. I would focus my concerns on the oil pressure sensor very soon. The oil sending unit is under pressure, the oil pan is merely a container for the oil.The oil pump has the capacity to empty all the oil out of the engine in less than a minute at high rpm. If the oil sending unit were to fail physically, meaning it fails to seal in the oil, the engine bearings will quickly run out of oil and be damaged. This will require an engine rebuild or new engine.

Comment: Very good points.

Answer (score 4):

An oil leak where you see a drip form, but it doesn't drip is not an *immediate* problem. If this is something you don't want to fix right away, there shouldn't be a huge issue. There are two concerns:

- Keep a close eye on the oil and ensure it stays topped off. You'll want to check it a little more often than you would under normal circumstances so as to avoid running your engine dry accidentally.
- Even though you don't see any drips coming off, be assured you are losing oil. This is not good for the environment and should be avoided. While you may not be able to make the fix right away, plan to do this as soon as possible.

Depending on where the oil pressure sensor is leaking from, you might be able to fix the issue. If it is leaking from around a threaded area, try and use some teflon tape on it and get the leak fixed. If the sensor is cracked or is leaking from somewhere else, it may just need replacement. Very simple fix and for the most part should be cheap.

On the oil pan, you may just see if the oil pan bolts are loose. Try putting a socket on them and see if they will tighten a little. This may stench the flow of the oil. I will caution you not to *over tighten* them. This would be easy to do. I don't know what torque value they should be, but don't go cranking down on them because you'll more than likely just make the leak worse.